# Magento 2.3.4 Customer registration email is not sent customer

Tags: magento2.3.4, customer-emails

In Magento 2.3.4 customer registration, forgot password emails are not working.

Admin configurations are done.

**Store > Configurations > Customer > Customer Configurations > Customer New Account Options** and **Password Options** load the templates.

Crontab is also added. But emails are not sending to customer

Is it mandatory SMTP extension in magento 2.3.4 to send an email for customer registration and forgot password?

Please help on this?

Comment: Check first sendmail or postfix logs on the server. Or check do you any of  them on the server.

Comment: check cron_schedule table  if there are any errors.